# Get URL that invoked the AWS HTTP API using Lambda - Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-http-api

I want to build some routes for my todos, example:

- List
- Get
- etc

So in order to do this I thought to check for the URL invoking the API (please if there is a better way call me out). I'm trying it out in a simple lambda first but can't get the URL, this is what I tried:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    let itsCallingFrom = event.requestContext.pathParameters;
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Calling from: ' + itsCallingFrom),
    };
    return response;
};
```

This is how my Route looks:

```
/listalltodos
    GET
```

This is what the event shows:

[image]

This is what I get: `"Calling from: undefined"`

Any idea how to get it?

Thanks

Comment: A bit late to the party, but: The `pathParameters` are in the `event` not in the `event.requestContext` ...  Furthermore `event.pathParameters` is an object so concatenating to a string might give some unexpected result (ie it's stringified as `[object Object]`) But as your route doesn't seem to have any parameters (for instance some element id or similar, ie a variable part in the path) `event.pathParameters` may also be `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form of `event` object in HTTP api is shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.proxy-format). It does not have a parameter such as `pathParameters`.

Instead you can use:

- `event.rawQueryString`
- `event.rawPath`

Or if you just want parameters then you can use:

- `event.queryStringParameters` - this will not be present if parameters are not provided, so you can use:

```
let itsCallingFrom = event.queryStringParameters || 'none';
```

Comment: Excellent, I was looking for `event.rawPath` that worked :) Thanks Marcin

Comment: Maybe the documentation changed in the meantime, but the referenced documentation clearly states, that there is indeed a `event.pathParameters` (although it might not always be present if the matched route doesn't define any parameters)